# CSS, divs moving around on content update

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, 2048

I'm trying to code 2048 using HTML/ CSS/ JS

I got the layout of the grid using this Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>2048</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class="gridd">
      <div><h1></h1></div>
      <div><h1></h1></div>
      <div><h1></h1></div>
      <div><h1></h1></div>
      <div><h1></h1></div>
      <div><h1></h1></div>
      <div><h1></h1></div>
      <div><h1></h1></div>
      <div><h1></h1></div>
    </div>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And for it I'm using this CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #C2C2C2;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Asap,sans-serif;
    font-size: 24pt;
    margin-top:35%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}


.gridd {
    width: 340px;
    height: 340px; 
    background-color: #B4B4B4;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    padding: 15px; 
    position: absolute; 
    margin: auto;
}

.gridd > div {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color:#787878; 
    border-radius: 15px; 
    margin:5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 80px 0 0 200px;

}
```

I'm simply using this JS code to generate the initial twos on the grid:

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

var y = document.getElementsByTagName("H1");

y[getRandomInt(8)].innerHTML = 2;
y[getRandomInt(8)].innerHTML = 2;
```

Now, on load I'm getting this unpleasant scene:

[image: 2048 wrecked loading]

Can someone help me understand what's going on please?
And how to fix it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you dont actually sue a grid while you shoud use one. Read into CSS-grid, this should easily solve the issue for you. Dont use absolute or elative positioning, do a clean 3x3 css grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `flex` rules for selector `.gridd`:

```
.gridd{
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

And replace `display: inline-block` with `flex: auto` in the selector `.gridd >div`:

```
.gridd >div{
    ...  
    flex: auto;
}
```

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

var y = document.getElementsByTagName("H1");

y[getRandomInt(8)].innerHTML = 2;
y[getRandomInt(8)].innerHTML = 2;
```

```css
*{margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: #C2C2C2;
}

h1{
    font-family: Asap,sans-serif;
    font-size: 24pt;
    margin-top:35%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}


.gridd{
    width: 340px;
    height: 340px; 
    background-color: #B4B4B4;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    padding: 15px; 
    position: absolute; 
    margin: auto;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

.gridd >div{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color:#787878; 
    border-radius: 15px; 
    margin:5px;
    
    flex: auto;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 80px 0 0 200px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>2048</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "gridd" >
        <div> <H1></H1> </div>

        <div> <H1></H1> </div>

        <div> <H1></H1> </div>

        <div> <H1></H1> </div>

        <div> <H1></H1> </div>

        <div> <H1></H1> </div>

        <div> <H1></H1> </div>

        <div> <H1></H1> </div>

        <div> <H1></H1> </div>
        
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script(-->
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, learning alot from the answers, would you please care to explain to me what is it in my code that was causing the problem?

Comment: @Majd, In general, your problem can be solved in different ways. My way with `flex` is like one of the options. And the reason for the violation of the order of the `gridd >div` is the default rule `display: block` you have `h1`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply fixed with changed to css file. use `display: grid`.

Also, do not use `margin-top: 35%;`. If you will make `h1`, or `div`, smaller or bigger, you will have to change the percentage too. Instead, you can center it via `align-items: center`.

This is the entire css file to fix the issue:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 80px 0 0 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #b4b4b4;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.gridd {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  gap: 5px;
}

.gridd > div {
  background-color: #787878;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}
```

It will center your `h1` no matter what text size it is and no matter how big your `div` container.

EDIT

In fact, this entire thing can be made without a `wrapper` and extra `div`

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}

.grid {
  margin: 80px 0 0 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #b4b4b4;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  gap: 5px;
}

.grid > h1 {
  background-color: #787878;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, learning alot from the answers, would you please care to explain to me what is it in my code that was causing the problem?

Comment: Mainly, its the overuse of `position: absolute;`. They are tedious to manage, especially if you have multiple of them to control your content areas. If one of the content areas become larger or smaller because your content changed, the layout can change too and mess up. Since JS loads after css and html, the content gets added up and the absolute div container becomes bigger and that messed up the layout. `position: absolute;` should only be used in case when you require a container to go outside his parents container. For example: a drop-down menu list. Hope it helps, @Majd

Comment: Also, as user `sergey kuznetsov` posted with the answer of using `display: flex` is also correct. But flex is really old. CSS-grid is newer and getting pushed out in real life more and more. But like with every great thing there r cons. Css-grid does not work on all browsers. There are few browsers that are not up to date with all css features. But majority of most popular browsers support is with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style a grid layout, you should also use a grid. The tool for it is called CSS-Grid. It delcared by using `display: grid;`. To have th grid 3 column wide, you use `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);`. Thatw ay you have 3 columns with the width of the children. To have a gap between the different chidlren cards, you use `grid-gap: 15px;`

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

var y = document.getElementsByTagName("H1");

y[getRandomInt(8)].innerHTML = 2;
y[getRandomInt(8)].innerHTML = 2;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #C2C2C2;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin-top: 35%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.gridd {
  width: min-content;
  padding: 15px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #B4B4B4;
  border-radius: 15px; 
}

.gridd>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #787878;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>2048</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gridd">
      <div>
        <H1></H1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <H1></H1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <H1></H1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <H1></H1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <H1></H1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <H1></H1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <H1></H1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <H1></H1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <H1></H1>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script(-->

</html>
```

Comment: should NOT be using `margin-top: 35%;` to center the text. In fact, even in your example, the text is not centered. the bottom has `27px` left while the top is `35px`. Also, this would not automatically change it if `h1` text size would be changed. instead, should use `align-items: center` or `transform`, but since css-grid already is in use, `align-items: center` does the job

Comment: after you edited your code. I just copied your code, merged it, and implemented a grid. All other stylings are purely your code. You asked how to fix the misaligning you caused yb absolute and relative positioning, which was fixed. it never was about somethign else.

Comment: ? I'm... not the person who asked this question. I'm just a person who provided an answer and info, to any other reader, why `margin-top: 35%;` in this case should not be used. Sorry for misunderstanding or getting you upset in any way, but I'm not Majd (the question author).

Comment: Thanks alot, learning alot from the answers, would you please care to explain to me what is it in my code that was causing the problem?